# How to test hypothesis using ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, multiple-regression, ordinal-data

I have data collected on likert scale (multiple items averaged) measurement. Initially I planned to carry out multiple regression analysis to test my hypothesis that 6 IVs explain some portion of a DV, but many argues that I should use ordinary logistic regression as my data is not continues and regression analysis requires continuous data. I have tried to run regression and only one IV is significantly affecting my DV. Beside this I should test regression assumptions which is not working. Two questions here:

1. Can I test hypothesis such as " Performance expectancy will significantly affect Symbolic Adoption" with some coefficient for IV. What about the final model that should say "these independent variables explained some percent of variation in DV"?
2. If I choose to go with multiple regression analysis, can I ignore the assumptions?
   Thanks